# Jest mocking return value of a static method of connected component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am unit testing my React app with jest and enzyme and all is good until I happened to test a class component connected with Redux. I went ahead and tested it by wrapping the component with a  and then shallow mounting it. However I am not able to mock return value of the static methods defined in my connected component.

Below is my sample code:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <TestComponent {...props}  />
    </Provider>
).dive();
```

Now when I try to mock the return value of static method defined in TestComponent, it doesn't have any effect, it fails:

```
TestComponent.myStaticMethod = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);
```

Interesting part is, if I export the unconnected component as also [suggested](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests/#connected-components) in redux docs, the above mock syntax work well. Is it fine to export the unconnected component just for the purpose of testing? I tried mocking before the shallow and then after it, both ways didn't work.

Comment: You're having trouble because you're violating the philosophical purpose of testing. Nothing in the component should need to be mocked. Only outer dependencies. If an internal `static` needs to have mocked values injected into it, it's a sign that it doesn't belong inside `TestComponent`

Answer (score 0):

`connect` returns a new component so you cannot override the static methods of the wrapped component in this way, (which is not a good idea like Andrew said)

But assuming this is what you want to do, you can mock the `connect` function from `react-redux` to return the original component

then pass all the props it gets from `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` as a standard React props

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

jest.mock('react-redux' () => ({
   connect: () => Component => Component
}))

MyComponent.myStaticMethod = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);


shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>)
```